# GPS tracker identification based on NMEA protocol

Tags: gps, nmea

I have several vehicles equiped each with individual GPS tracker sending NMEA stream to a server.

Prior to storage at the server side, I want to be able to uniquely identify each vehicle.

Is that possible using NMEA protocol?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to see to what extent your GPS trackers support the NMEA specification.

You should be able to retrieve the data you need from the sentence`$GPSTN`. 
This will be received as `$--STN,xx` where `xx` is an ID number.

Comment: Thanks I was looking fr something like that itself.

Answer (score 0):

you can able to uniquely identify each vehicle by choosing port for each device.

example :
vehicle001 IP `: xx.xx.xx.xx` Port 50001 
vehicle002 IP : `xx.xx.xx.xx` Port 50002
vehicle003 IP : `xx.xx.xx.xx` Port 50003